# Group Policy Separation: opinions

Tags: windows-server-2008

Pertaining to Windows Server 2008 +/- 6 years: Just wondering, but when I create group policy for domains, I usually create this to one master file. The size of this Active Directory is normally for small, less-than-ten-user entities, and controlling these spaces is done largely through GP. When a new computer is added, for instance, the desktop is completely modified/prepared to resemble all others' Internet rules, file and directory shares, proxy blocks are added, Desktop icons are added/removed, and more.

What is the real advantage for creating multiple separate GP Organizational Units? Do you practice this (i.e. One makes nineteen separate policies, one for each rule)? At what size is the threshold where you make multiple.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, A lot of group policy design is about common sense.  If you have a group of settings that apply globally to all computers/users in your domain, you only need a single GPO to hold them.  If at some point a subset of those settings no longer apply to everyone or apply differently to different groups, split them out into their own GPOs.  If it's a small group of settings that all revolve around a specific function, I generally try to name the policy for the function rather than for the computers/users they apply to.  So `Firewall - No Inbound Blocking` and `Firewall - Standard Blocking` instead of `Firewall - Dept A` and `Firewall - Dept B`.

There is a processing "cost" for each GPO a computer has to process, but on today's computers it's pretty minimal.  Don't go crazy and create a policy for each setting you want to apply.  But don't worry about adding 5 instead of 1.

Comment: To better describe my environments, I make everything under a single Organizational Unit. For each rule I create, I either make it for all, or specify an and/or/except condition, citing either an active directory group or single computer.

I wonder when it would get to be a major problem. That, or if someone has the mantra of making a unique Organizational Unit for each and every single rule or group of rules, i.e. desktop icons; time server url; etc.